# Connecting different switches together

Tags: networking, switch

If I have a 100Mbps cable and I connect it to a 10 Mbps switch and to that switch I connect another 100 Mbps switch, will that 100 Mbps switch connected at the last get 100Mbps speed?
Is there a defect in such a connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two 100Mbps switches can switch down to 10Mbps, the connection will be at 10Mbps due to the intervening switch.

If one or both of the switches *can't* switch down (but they probably can), you'll have no connection between them at all.

Comment: and will I get 100 Mbps after the last 100 Mbps?

Comment: Every connection that doesn't have to go through the 10Mbps switch can reach 100Mbps.

Answer (score 1):

Data travelling through the daisy chained ports will do so at the speed of the slowest switch.

Comment: I type too slow

Comment: So the speed of the slowest switch goes out?

Comment: Each individual port on the switch should auto-negotiate with the device connected to it for it's max speed setting. A 10Mbps connection can operate between devices on two ports of a 100Mbps switch AT THE SAME TIME AS two other ports on the same switch passing data between devices at 100Mbps. BUT, any data that passes through your 10Mbps switch or that is sent/received by a 10Mps Network Interface Card (NIC) will only do so at 10Mbps regardless of what other equipment is connected to it.